# Export Kafka Topic to MySql

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Often for debug purposes, I would like analyze/inspect messages in a Kafka Topic.

I believe we can write connectors to export data from Kafka Topics to MySql DB.

Before I dive deep into it, I would like ensure if it's a viable approach ? If so can you please point me to an example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to write any custom code. It's all there already. Just use Kafka Connect and one of the existing MySQL connectors available via Confluent web page: https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/